# Edit channel fields view displaying short name not field label, with no link to edit

Tags: control-panel, channel-fields

Since I upgraded from 2.5.5 to 2.10.1, I can no longer edit channel fields.

When attempting to edit channel fields, the edit view displays the fields listed by short name in input tags, instead of by field label in links.

It appears there's some javascript that's hiding the field label instead of the short name, as both are present in the DOM. No idea where it could be coming from, however.

No errors are shown.

Here is a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Are you a Super Admin? And can you list what Accessories you have installed?

Comment: Yes, Super Admin.
Draggable 1.3
NSM Morphine Theme 2.0.4
Primary Category 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling Draggable first, then if that doesn't work, NSM Morphine Theme. Be careful, I think there are a few random addons out their that depend on NSM Morhpine Theme. Do your usually due diligence: **Back it up first**.

Comment: Needed to update Draggable. Thanks for your help.